# SQL Server Reporing Services Deployment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 U3. Recently I have installed [SQL Server Reporting Services Deployment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tobania.SqlReportingServices#overview)  (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tobania.SqlReportingServices#overview)  in Market place.

Here is my question:

I think this is not an issue with extension but my question is how to handle the process.

Each time my release task runs it will deploy all RDL files in my project. Is there a way to only deploy new/ Changed RDL's(Is it possible to Deploy only new and modified reports (RDL files) using TFS Deployment?)
Thanks,

Satheesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's the expected behavior with the extension which deploy all RDL files in the project. It will relace all the previous files. Only deploy the new and modified reports (RDL files) is not supported.

However you can try deploy the files singly with powershell, below articles may helps:

[PowerShell Commands for SQL Server Reporting Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4738/powershell-commands-for-sql-server-reporting-services/)